# Как вставить значение в середину огромного файла?

Tags: c#, файлы, хеширование

Есть бинарный файл 30Гб. Содержит отсортированные md5-хеши, записаны как массивы байт, один за другим. 
Есть ли способ добавить новый хеш в этот файл без перезаписи всех бОльших значений?

Comment: Возможно, я избрал не верный способ хранения большого кол-ва хешей. Буду рад советам.

Comment: Вставить (не заменить) в файл без перезаписи хвоста нельзя. Видимо, способ действительно не очень. А чтобы посоветовать, что лучше - надо задачу понимать.

Comment: а насчет бд не думали

Comment: @АлександрЛи Проще всего будет использовать любую БД и таблицу с индексом. Но если вы хотите с нуля написать что-то свое, то можете попробовать реализовать подобие хеш-таблицы, которая будет находится на диске. Места будет занимать больше, но поиск и вставка будут быстрые.

Comment: Значит бд. Весь мой опыт говорит, что это медленно. И я совсем не представляю, как организовать бинарный поиск по бд.

Comment: По сторонней БД с помощью sql команд обычно :) `select myhash from mytable where myhash = 12345` как то так

Comment: А какие операции с этими данными вы делаете? Пока известно только, что нужны вставки в середину. Это частая операция или очень редкая? В комментариях упомянут бинарный поиск. А что ещё нужно? Невозможно посоветовать подходящую структуру данных, не зная, для каких операций она предназначена.

Comment: Мне необходимо быстро проверять наличие значения в базе и за разумное время добавлять в базу новые значения(возможно что новых значение будет много). 
Вставка в середину была необходима исключительно ради бинарного поиска.